# How to import a .sql file file into Django models and query it

Tags: python, postgresql, django-database, django-datatable

I have a single file with data in it with a .sql extension. I want to be able to query it and display results using Django Templates and Views. How do I even access it in my Django Project.

Anyone please

I have tried to create a server for the file using PostgreSQL and then connect my Django database to it. But I can’t seem to get around that.

Comment: if u implement your server in docker or other way you can run your sql query in postgresql before server start

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.